# How to compile C++ source code ("iostream.h not found" error)?

Tags: compiling, c++

I do not want to discuss about C++ or any programming language!I just want to know what am i doing wrong with linux ubuntu about compiling helloworld.cpp!

I am learning C++ so my steps are:

open hello.cpp in vim and write this

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";`
    return 0;
}
```

So, after that i tried in the terminal this

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

AND the output is

```
hello.cpp:1:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What do you suggest? Any useful step by step guide for me?Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone is considering voting to close this question as off-topic: This really is a platform-specific issue, because the most popular C++ compiler for Windows (Microsoft Visual C++) accepts this syntax, but most other compilers (including `g++` in Ubuntu) do not accept it.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std; int main()
{ cout << "Hello World"; return 0;
} this can work...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use `#include <iostream>`, not `iostream.h`; the *.h* form is very old and deprecated since years.

You can read more than you probably want to know on the *.h* vs non-*.h* forms here:
http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html

(Plus, you should write `std::cout` or have a line `using namespace std;` otherwise your next error will be about the compiler not finding a definition for `cout`.)

Comment: Thanks! Well i am trying to learn C++ in 21 days.. From this [guide](http://newdata.box.sk/bx/c/htm/ch01.htm). Just saw what you said about std in this [guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-c-and-c-compilers-in-ubuntu-and-testing-your-first-c-and-c-program.html). So i am wondering if my first guide is wrong or the C++ is changing between os.! Is that possible???thanksWhat is the std?

Comment: @gabriel C++ has a long history, dating back to the mid-1980.  There are now several published standards, the latest of which (C++11) has been released earlier this year, and the previous one (the one that all compilers follow today) dates back to 2003 (C++03).  The guide you linked seems to be much older than that though, judging from the compiler software it mentions (according to Wikipedia, Borland Turbo C++ was discontinued in 1994). If you pick a tutorial following the C++03 standard, your code will work on any Linux distribution available today.

Comment: Thank you very much! Any tutorial about it?Thanks

Comment: @gabriel Sorry, I do not have any suggestion for a uptodate tutorial. Maybe ask another question?

Comment: @gabriel Looks like your question has been already answered on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909323/what-are-good-online-resources-or-tutorials-to-learn-c

Comment: You may also need: **sudo apt-get install build-essential**

Comment: @david6: I have *build-essential* installed but there's no `iostream.h` on my system.  Actually, C++ header files are installed by *libstdc++-dev*, which is required by the C++ compiler package *g++*, which in turn is required by *build-essential*.  So, no, you do not need *build-essential* to compile simple C++ programs; installing the `g++` package is enough.

Comment: Ok, then read this: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-144311.html

Comment: @david6: Indeed, *build-essential* is never mentioned there.

Comment: For just getting `cout` to work without the `std::` prefix, `using std::cout;` is preferable to `using namespace std;`. Even multiple `using` statements (without `namespace`) are generally better, since you don't bring in identifiers from the `std` namespace that you don't want and might conflict with names in your own program.

Answer (score 16):

You should change `iostream.h` to `iostream`. I was also getting the same error as you are getting, but when I changed `iostream.h` to just `iostream`, it worked properly. Maybe it would work for you as well.

In other words, change the line that says:

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

Make it say this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
```

The C++ standard library header files, as defined in the standard, do not have `.h` extensions.

As mentioned [Riccardo Murri's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/130784/22949), you will also need to call `cout` by its fully qualified name `std::cout`, or have one of these two lines (preferably below your `#include` directives but above your other code):

```
using namespace std;
```

```
using std::cout;
```

The second way is considered preferable, especially for serious programming projects, since it only affects `std::cout`, rather than bringing in all the names in the `std` namespace (some of which might potentially interfere with names used in your program).

Comment: Great answer. In answering @gabriel's question you've resolved a couple side confusions I've had for years.