# what is wrong .h

Tags: 12.04, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile C++ source code (“iostream.h not found” error)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130781/how-to-compile-c-source-code-iostream-h-not-found-error)

I have aquired C++ for dummies, old for a windows GNU compiler. And I get this error, thinking it needs a different variable of the iostream?[image]I'm new to this I know I am not posting the way it should look.  Like the screen shot is very small, sorry If I cannot get a response I'll try a different angle.

Comment: I can't see a single character on that screenshot. So either upload a bigger one (maybe only the editor part, not whole screen) or, even better, just post your code.

Comment: Check this previous post 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/130781/how-to-compile-c-source-code-iostream-h-not-found-error

Comment: Try asking on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `<iostream.h>` which is deprecated in c++, Instead of that you have to use `#include<iostream>`

Comment: thanks guys I'll know better next time to just post code.  I'm using a 2000 C++ for dummies and it seems things have changed since then.thanks #Tachyons